# Convert an array into cumulative% array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this one:

`[30, 10, 4, 3, 3]`

And I need to transform this to a cumulative% array in such a way that each value is the sum of all values upto there divided by sum of all values in the array.

In this case, the total is 50. So, the first value will be `30/50, i.e., 0.6 or 60%. The 2nd value will be (30+10)/50, i.e., 0.8 or 80%` and so on.

The final array in this will be:

`[60%, 80%, 88%, 94%, 100%]`

How can I do this transformation with JavaScript? What would be the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: What have u tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try,

```
var x = [30, 10, 4, 3, 3];
var y = x.reduce(function(a,b){ return a+b; }, 0)
x = x.map(function(itm, index){
  for(var i=0;i<index;i++) itm += x[i];
  return (itm/y * 100);
});

x; //[60, 80, 88, 94, 100]
```

And this will look more elegant,

```
var x = [30, 10, 4, 3, 3];
var y = x.reduce(function(a,b){ return a+b; }, 0), sum = 0;
x = x.map(function(itm) { return sum += itm, (sum / y) * 100; });
```

Comment: @asanas Glad to help! :)

Comment: Recalculating the cumulative sums over and over again does not seem very elegant.

Comment: @torazaburo Now? Is this ok to remove your downvote on this? And I like your attitude in adding valuable comments to the answers.

Comment: Hi there. It is a question of how picky one wants to be. Unfortunately, I think, with all due respect, this answer is still less than perfect. The reason is that it adds up all the numbers twice, once to find the total, and then again in computing the percentages. In the real world that wouldn't matter, and your code would pass review and get merged and we would go on with our lives. But if one is intent on pursuing the absolutely best solution, there is still a way to go. The basic question is: how can I solve this while adding the numbers up only once?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
let nums = [30, 10, 4, 3, 3];
let sum = nums.reduce((prev,curr) => prev + curr);
let result = nums.map((num,i) => Math.round(nums.slice(0,i + 1).reduce((prev,curr) => prev + curr) / sum * 100) + '%');
```

Comment: This will return `["60%", "20%", "8%", "6%", "6%"]` This is not OP have asked for.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy My bad. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to compute the sum to get the denominator (*50*).
Then you need to apply the treatment for each element (`new_value=value/denominator`)

To do so you can use simple for loops, or even *cleaner* with arrays specific functions, to avoid any error:

```
var array = [30, 10, 4, 3, 3];

// Compute the denominator
var sum = array.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
// Duplicate the array
var arrayResult = array;
// Apply the function to each given "myArray[ind]" element
arrayResult.forEach( function(cv,ind,myArray) {
    myArray[ind] = cv/sum;
    // Add the previous accumulator if any
    if( ind>0 ) {myArray[ind] += myArray[ind-1];}
} );
```

[See it running on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0u9cyv6/1)

**edited to add the accumulator**

Answer (score 0):

Combine two maps, one to create an array with cumulative sums, the second to divide by the sum.

```
function cumulative_ratio(array) {
  var x = 0;
  return array . 
    map(v => x += v) .
    map(v => v / x);
}
```